# Крон скрипты - защита от случайных выполнений

Tags: cron, php

Есть скрипт, который отправляет письма с уведомлениями два раза в день по крону. Как защитится от его выполнения, если вдруг случайно перейдут по адресу этого скрипта, или его найдёт поисковый робот, или ещё как..
Я пока нашёл одно решение: в бд записать время последнего выполнения, и при выполнении проверить, прошло ли 12 часов с последнего запуска.
Ещё есть мысль проверять заголовки, но я без понятия, как это делать.
Подскажите что-нибудь?

Comment: При проверке точно на 12 часов и запуску по крону 2 раза в день скрипт может отрабатывать только один раз в день.

Comment: @avp, конечно я эту учту, и буду проверять примерно 11 часов 55 минут, я спрашивал про оптимальность этого способа в принципе

Comment: @Dazar, в принципе, IMHO, это просто надуманная проблема.

Если на сайте бардак, то кто-нибудь рано или поздно накосячит. Причем серьезно. Например, диск форматнет (или хуже - восстановится со столетнего бэкапа, а свежие удалит).

Comment: А есть смысл этот скрипт в www папке хранить ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно вынести этот скрипт в подпапку, которую закрыть через .htaccess, тогда снаружи до него никак не достучатся.